# Login with Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have successfully created login with Facebook API, when user logins auth token is returned. But how can I get user details from Facebook API? What kind of query I have to make to Facebook API to get logged in users name etc. details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use 'me' to denote the logged in user and use the access_token to access all permitted resources like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...
```

Also you can access all permitted fields using below:

```
Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...
News feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=...
Profile feed (Wall): https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...
Likes: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=...
Movies: https://graph.facebook.com/me/movies?access_token=...
Music: https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=...
Books: https://graph.facebook.com/me/books?access_token=...
Notes: https://graph.facebook.com/me/notes?access_token=...
Permissions: https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=...
Photo Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=...
Photo Albums: https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=...
Video Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos?access_token=...
Video Uploads: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos/uploaded?access_token=...
Events: https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=...
Groups: https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token=...
Checkins: https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?access_token=...
```

Full information is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/