# Using Yii2 authClient to retrieve scope data from Facebook after successful authentication

Tags: facebook, oauth, yii2

Currently working with the Yii2 framework and using the includable `\yiisoft\yii2-authclient` OAuth abstraction class. I am able to connect and authenticate via Facebook but can not figure out how to access secondary data available through the OAuth2 scope configuration option.

Related but vague (as it does not explain how scope applies to the situation nor how to use the authClient to retrieve the data: [Login with Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010477/login-with-facebook-api)

Config

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        'facebook' => [
            'authUrl'      => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
            'class'        => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
            'clientId'     => '*****',
            'clientSecret' => '*****',
            'scope'        => [
                'email', 
                'public_profile', 
                'user_about_me', 
                'user_location', 
                'user_work_history',
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

Controller setup:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'auth' => [
            'class'           => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [$this, 'onAuthSuccess'],
        ],
    ];
}
...
/**
 * [onAuthSuccess description]
 *
 * @param  [type] $client [description]
 * @return [type]         [description]
 */
public function onAuthSuccess($client)
{
    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $attributes );
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
...
```

The returned object is as follows:

```
yii\authclient\clients\Facebook Object
(
    [authUrl] => https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    [tokenUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    [apiBaseUrl] => https://graph.facebook.com
    [scope] => Array
        (
            [0] => email
            [1] => public_profile
            [2] => user_about_me
            [3] => user_location
            [4] => user_work_history
        )

    [attributeNames] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => email
        )

    [version] => 2.0
    ...
)
```

How would I access the user's `user_about_me` data?

*Edited to add controller logic that provides the data dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getUserAttributes` method:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback']
        ]
    ];
}

/**
 * @param OAuth2 $client
 */
public function successCallback($client)
{
    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
    ...
}
```

Comment: $client->getUserAttributes() only returns the following:

Array
(
    [name] => *****
    [email] => *****
    [id] => *****
)

Passing a scope such as `user_about_me` as a paramater the same array is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can get following info by setting this values in `attributeNames`

```
id
name
first_name
last_name
age_range
link
gender
locale
picture
timezone
updated_time
verified
```

In your config file

```
...
'components' => [
    ...
    'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            'facebook' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
                'clientId' => 'YOUR APP CLIENT ID',
                'clientSecret' => 'YOUR APP CLIENT SECRET',
                'attributeNames' => [
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'link',
                    'about',
                    'work',
                    'education',
                    'gender',
                    'email',
                    'timezone',
                    'locale',
                    'verified',
                    'updated_time',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    ...
],
...
```

Important Links and references

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

[Login with Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010477/login-with-facebook-api)

[What data can be obtained about a user who logs in with Facebook Oauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816359/what-data-can-be-obtained-about-a-user-who-logs-in-with-facebook-oauth)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&version=v2.7

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: Yes, after more digging around and playing with different OAuth providers we did finally get this working the way we wanted. While OAuth is an industry standard process it is such a pain that every provider implements it differently. :S